# Check whether Windows updates are available

Tags: windows, winapi

is there any programmatically possiblity to check whether Windows has new updates available?

Any advice is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Sample code: http://www.scms.waikato.ac.nz/~harry/wsusupdate.vbs

Answer (score 5):

The [Window Update Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387287%28VS.85%29.aspx) API, if this is for a domain environment also look at [WSUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms744624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).