# c# - Get list of windows updates programatically from XP,Vista and 7

Tags: c#, .net

How to get the list of windows updates which are installed and which are remaining programatically?

i want to run this code on XP, Vista and Windows 7..

i want both the list .. installed updates and yet to install updates

how to do that in c#?

Comment: There are links to [com](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387099(v=vs.85).aspx) and [.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms744624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) APIs mentioned in the answer to the similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725924/check-whether-windows-updates-are-available